# Finding $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\cos(xy) -1}{x^2 y^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the following limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\cos(xy) -1}{x^2 y^2}$$

I did the following:

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{\cos(x)-1}{x^2}$ and $g(x,y) = xy$. Then we would have $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\cos(xy) -1}{x^2 y^2} =  \frac{\cos(\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} xy) -1}{(\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} xy)^2}=0$$

Is my procedure correct? What are other approaches one could have with these limits? Thanks.

Comment: What you got was $0/0$ not $0$.

Answer (score 4):

What you did is not correct, since what you got was $\frac00$.

If $x,y\in\Bbb R$, then$$\frac{\cos(xy)-1}{x^2y^2}=-\frac12+\frac1{4!}(xy)^2-\frac1{6!}(xy)^4+\cdots$$and therfore$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos(xy)-1}{x^2y^2}=-\frac12.$$

Comment: Thanks. How do you manipulate the expansion of the cosine to make it correspond to $\frac{\cos(xy)-1}{x^2 y^2}$ ? Or is the series expansion of $\frac{\cos{x}-1}{x^2}$ an identity?

Comment: It's bacause$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R):\cos(x)=1-\frac1{2!}x^2+\frac1{4!}x^4-\frac1{6!}x^6+\cdots$$In other words, the Taylor series of the cosine function centered at $0$ converges to $\cos x$ for every $x\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos(xy)-1}{x^2y^2}= -\lim_\limits{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2\sin^2 \frac{xy}{2}}{x^2y^2} = -\lim_\limits{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\sin^2 \frac{xy}{2}}{2\left(\frac{xy}{2}\right)^2} = \\ =-\dfrac{1}{2} \lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2} = -\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Good use of the trig identity! But there is an error in sign: $\cos(xy)-1=-2\sin^2\frac{xy}2$

Comment: Of course you are right. Haste. Edited. Thanks.